# Wget not downloading files from NASA’s Earthdata website

Tags: cygwin, wget

I am using Cygwin64 on Windows 10 to download files via Wget from NASA’s Earthdata website. I seem to be following the correct procedure [as explained on their website](https://support.earthdata.nasa.gov/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/43/21/how-to-access-urs-gated-data-with-curl-and-wget), but for some reason, Wget is not downloading the files. I just see a blinking cursor.

```
wget -q --spider machine urs.earthdata.nasa.gov

touch .netrc

echo "machine urs.earthdata.nasa.gov login baloch444 password *********" >> .netrc

touch .urs_cookies

wget --load-cookies .urs_cookies --save-cookies .urs_cookies --auth-no-challenge=on --keep-session-cookies --content-disposition --no-check-certificate --user=baloch444 --ask-password -I myfile.dat
```

Comment: have you tried the obvious.. do `wget http://blah/blah.html`   See if that works no blinking cursor. Then try adding stuff.  Then that may help you figure out what is wrong with your command

Comment: Why are you using `machine urs.earthdata.nasa.gov` instead of the more basic, `https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov`? So your command would be `wget -q --spider `https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov`. Also, what version of Wget are you using? Their site mentions differences between how to use Wget 1.11.1 and higher versus Wget 1.11 and lower.

Comment: Yes, Jake you are right, machine was causing the problem, I changed it to https, and it's working now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @JakeGould can you post that as an answer for Saad to accept? Thanks

Comment: @Saad Answer posted. If it helped you, please be sure to upvote it. And if it is the answer that solved your problem, please be sure to check it off as such.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using `machine urs.earthdata.nasa.gov` instead of the more basic, `https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov`? So your command would be

```
wget -q --spider https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov
```

Also, what version of Wget are you using?

[Their site mentions](https://support.earthdata.nasa.gov/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/43/21/how-to-access-urs-gated-data-with-curl-and-wget) differences between how to use Wget 1.11.1 and higher versus Wget 1.11 and lower:

> “Note: Starting with version 1.11.1, Wget requires the `--auth-no-challenge` option to authenticate properly to URS. Versions prior to 1.11 should omit the `--auth-no-challenge` option. Version 1.11 of Wget will not work at all.”